# Nuxt 3 - code change in composable generates ReferenceError

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

**Introduction**
I am using nuxt for some small university projects, but I mention something that is quite anoying, but I could not find any ticket on the Nuxt 3 github or any mention on stackoverflow.

**Problem**
If I start my new nuxt 3 project using the code below as described on the nuxt website under the [installation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation) section

```
npx nuxi init <project-name>
```

Then in my project, I am creating a composables folder, were I would store my composables. In this example, I created a composable called `useBoxPlot`, which would provide the information for a boxplot. When I would then spin up the server using `yarn dev`, still ervery thing works fine.
**but then**, when I would change something within the composable file, the development server would restart, but i would get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: useData is not defined
    at app.vue:25:1
```

the composable would like something like this:

```js
export const useBoxPlot = async (el) => {
   //code here, change here is causing the error
})
```

I would need to control+c out of the console and start it again, each time I need to make a change. I encoutered this in all 3 projects I created from nuxt 3.0.0 untill now, I am using version 3.3.3.

**Conclusion**
I don't know where it is coming from.
Anybody knows what I could change? Or what I can do to make it better?

Comment: Is `useData` something you use within `useBoxPlot`?
Or is useBoxPlot doing something that only works on server side but not on client side? Because if the server starts up, everything is pre-rendered, but with hot reloading it's only rendered on the client side.
Or maybe `async` is causing the problem?
Just guessing, I've not seen this issue before.